# EF 6, Mapeamento com Fluent Api em classes com herança

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, fluent-api

Estou treinando o mapeamento de classes para o Entity Framework usando a Fluent API e estou com algumas dúvidas.

A primeira é a seguinte: Mapear uma **foreign key** com atributos seria assim:

```c-sharp
public int EmpresaId {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
public Empresa Empresa {get; set;}
```

Com a Fluent API seria assim:

```c-sharp
HasRequired(p => p.Empresa).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaId);
```

Correto isso? O que não entendi é esse `WithMany()` já que é uma ligação simples de chave estrangeira e não é uma `ICollection<>`, por exemplo. Então porque desse `WithMany()`?

A outra dúvida seria, como ficaria o mapeamento com a Fluent API dessas classes, já que duas herdam da primeira?

```c-sharp
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
}

public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
{
    public string CPF {get; set;}
}

public class PessoaJuridica : Pessoa
{
    public string CNPJ {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### WithMany

Usa-se `WithMany()` para especificar um relacionamento Many. O que está mesmo esquisito é o fato de você estar usando `WithMany()` sem argumentos. `WithMany()` serve para você especificar a relação inversa.

Por exemplo, se aquele trecho de código se refere a uma pessoa, o correto seria o mapeamento ser assim:

```
HasRequired(p => p.Empresa)
    .WithMany(e => e.Pessoas)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaId);
```

### Classe Pessoa

Uma `Pessoa` em teoria só pode ser Física ou Jurídica, certo? O correto seria fazer assim:

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
}

public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
{
    public string CPF {get; set;}
}

public class PessoaJuridica : Pessoa
{
    public string CNPJ {get; set;}
}
```

Na Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaFisica>()
    .HasKey(pf => pf.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaFisica>()
    .Property(pf => pf.Nome)
    .HasMaxLength(70)
    .IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaJuridica>()
    .HasKey(pj => pj.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaJuridica>()
    .Property(pj => pj.Nome)
    .HasMaxLength(70)
    .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Poxa, não dá nem tempo de responder tu aparece aqui já respondendo ein... kkk vai ser ativo assim lá na china...
brincadeira...

Comment: Legal seu exemplo da classe `abstrata` de `Pessoa`, mas quanto a propriedade Nome, se via `Fluent API` eu quiser especificar que ela é requerida e tem um máximo de 70 caracteres, por exemplo, onde eu faria essa especificação?

Comment: @Tiago Vou editar a resposta pra você.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez mas ele poderia fazer um `DbSet<Pessoa>` e no `modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>.Property(p => p.Nome).IsRequired();` ele poderia fazer a validação não poderia? Pois ai através do `Descriminator` o framework se encarregaria de distribuir as classes corretamente não é? (ps: não dá pra testar agora [longe de um pc com visual studio/.net])

Comment: @tchicotti Pode. Também vale como exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Tiago, provavelmente sua classe deve ser algo assim:

```
public Pessoa {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
    public Empresa Empresa {get; set;}
}
```

Dai sua classe Empresa deve ser algo por volta de

```
public Empresa {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //... 
    public ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas {get; set;}
}
```

Estou certo?
Se for, o seu relacionamento do Fluent deverá representar da seguinte maneira:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Empresa)
            .WithMany(e => e.Pessoas)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaId);
```

O que acontece é o seguinte: A pessoa `Entity<Pessoa>` tem um campo obrigatório (requerido) `HasRequired(p => p.Empresa)` que faz parte de uma lista da empresa `WithMany(e => e.Pessoas);`

Ou seja, essa pessoa necessita ter uma empresa e essa pessoa estará vinculada as pessoas que existem naquela empresa (`ICollection`).

Comment: +1 pela resposta útil e relevante ;)

Comment: Sim, a estrutura das classes seriam essas. Creio então que minha falta de conhecimento foi na parte em que, já que uma Pessoa tem uma ligação a uma Empresa, na empresa eu TENHO QUE TER uma coleção de Pessoas que pertencem a ela. Seria esse o correto para o mapeamento para o EntityFramework? Esclarecendo melhor, eu não fiz essa `ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas`.

Comment: Essa propriedade `ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas` é uma `NavigationProperty` para que o `Context` saiba qual é o relacionamento entre as classes

Comment: @tchicotti, muito obrigado!

Comment: Só que, podem existir cenários onde eu faça algo como: `ctx.Empresas.Include(x=>x.Pessoas);` **?** Acho muito inviável isso, não é?

Comment: O `Include` serve para quando você tentar acessar suas propriedades dê Pessoa, não precisar buscar novamente no banco, mas o exemplo ICollection<Pessoa> foi só pra mostrar a existência da navigation property... Mas caso você queira manter assim e só carregar PessoaFisica vc pode usar ctx.Empresa.Pessoas.OfType<PessoaFisica>.Load()

Comment: @Tiago ja vou ver sim, só um instante que estou tendo que modelar umas tabelas de migração aqui no serviço e já vejo... :)