# Entity Framework - renomear ForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho as classes:

```
[Table("Editora")]
    public class Editora
    {
        [Key]
        public int EditoraID { get; set; }

        public string nome { get; set; }

        public List<Livro> livros { get; set; }

        public List<Telefone> telefone { get; set; } 
    }

public class Telefone
    {
        public int TelefoneID { get; set; }

        public string fixo { get; set; }

        public string cel { get; set; }
    }
```

Estou estudando o code first, fiz o update-database. Uma chave estrangeira ao Telefone foi criada pois há uma propriedade do tipo List Telefone em Editora. O nome dessa chave estrangeira foi criado com o nome padrão: "Editora_EditoraID", gostaria de renomeá-lo.

Comment: Renomear exatamente o que? Cite um exemplo claro, ou seja, o que aconteceu e que deseja que faça!

Comment: Como eu disse, renomear a foreignKey. Olhe para a minha classe Editora, há uma propriedade do tipo Telefone a qual criou uma chave estrangeira com o nome padrão, simplesmente gostaria de renomeá-la pelo code first.

Comment: Qual foi o nome que ela colocou na coluna do banco? ou seja, o tal nome padrão ? só quero entender!

Comment: No Telefone foi criada a FK: Editora_EditoraID

Comment: Eu entendi, você ainda não colocou as configurações e já rodou o migration correto? e agora quer arrumar os nomes dos campos correto?

Comment: Já fiz o migration e o update. Quero renomear só essa chave estrangeira.

Comment: Veja a minha respostas para renomear ela, a mesma precisa existir nas configurações eu fiz todo o processo para você!

Comment: Entendeu @HeyJoe?

Comment: Me parece que você não entendeu? ou entendeu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pelo que pude entender, você fez o esquema igual está na sua pergunta e o `migration` gerou por conta próprio os nomes dos campos pela sua forma padrão (*O migration tem a sua forma padrão de gerar, se não colocar as configurações o código gera os nomes inclusive as relações do seu modo*), isso acontece por falta de configuração inicial, o importante sempre é fazer o certo, e colocar as relações como você deseja, nomes e formas para não ter esses problemas, apesar que no seu caso não é um problema é só fazer o que precisa para que o mesmo gere um novo `migration` de atualização para resolver o problema.

<sub>***Exemplo minimo:***</sub>

As alterações devem serem feitas nas classes e rodar novamente a `Migration`

```
[Table("Editora")]
public class Editora
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EditoraID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[Table("Telefone")]
public class Telefone
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TelefoneID { get; set; }
    public string Fixo { get; set; }
    public string Cel { get; set; }

    public int EditoraID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EditoraID")]
    public virtual Editora Editora { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[Table("Livro")]
public class Livro
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LivroID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    public int EditoraID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EditoraID")]
    public virtual Editora Editora { get; set; }
}
```

Pronto com isso as configurações poderão ser atualizadas e com uma nomenclatura ideal, como:

Faça novamente o comandos:

```
add-migration update3
```

e depois

```
update-database
```

***Observação:*** esse é o minimo de configurações eu recomendaria o modo `Fluent API`, *links*:

- [Mapeamento com Entity Framework Code First (Fluent Api) – Parte 1](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-1/)
- [Mapeamento com Entity Framework Code First (Fluent Api) – Parte 2](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/)
- [EF 6, Mapeamento com Fluent Api em classes com herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9793/54880)
- [Using Entity Framework Code First Approach with Fluent API in an ASP.NET MVC application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/899/entity-framework-code-first-fluent-aspnet-mvc)

***Dica:*** a qualquer mudança nas suas classes que vão gerar novas configurações na sua base repita os comandos `add-migration` e depois `update-database` que as novas configurações ou alterações serão aplicadas.

Comment: Onde exatamente posso colocar o nome que eu quiser à chave estrangeira nesse código?

Comment: `[ForeignKey("EditoraID")]` é aonde você renomea ou coloca o nome da Propriedade ... @HeyJoe

Comment: Ah sim, eu coloco um nome qualquer de propriedade a qual é na verdade a FK e faço referência a ela com [ForeignKey("<propriedade>")]. Mas o que seria essa propriedade virtual de Editora?

Comment: Essa propriedade é para que você tenha a possibilidade de pegar informações da Editor, já visto que dentro da tabela Telefone só tem a identificação, mas, os dados não e por essa propriedade eu posso carregar! @HeyJoe

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se compreendi corretamente, mas creio que você está se referindo a chave estrangeira que o Entity cria automaticamente no banco de dados (normalmente: exemplo_ID), se for este o caso você pode defini-la manualmente.

1- Crie uma propriedade que representará sua chave estrangeira:

```
public class Telefone
{
    public int TelefoneID { get; set; }

    //Chave estrangeira para tabela editora
    public int EditoraID { get; set;}

    public string fixo { get; set; }

    public string cel { get; set; }

    //Propriedade que representará a relação entre as tabelas
    [ForeignKey("EditoraID")]
    public virtual Editora Editora { get; set; }
}
```

Pode ser necessário utilizar o comando "Update-Database -Force" para garantir que a atualização será feita.

obs: Pesquise também sobre fluent api para fazer este mapeamento
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx